# Is there a Dapper executenonquery? How do I know if my update worked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper

So I have a simple update using Dapper:

```
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
  {
          conn.Open();
          conn.Execute("UPDATE Orders SET Exported=1 WHERE ManufacturerID=@ManufactuterID AND OrderID=@OrderID",
                      new { ManufacturerID = ManufacturerID, OrderID = OrderID });
          conn.Close();
  }
```

How do I know that this actually worked?  I do not see a way to run ExecuteNonQuery using Dapper?

Comment: `Execute` returns an `int`.

Comment: wow, feeling pretty stupid - thanks

Comment: @Slee it can be easy to miss things. We need to call it something different because extension methods resolve *after* instance methods. Besides: we don't normally name things for what they aren't... So ExecuteNonQuery felt overkill as a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dapper is just a light wrapper around `IDbConnection`. Internally `Execute` will call `ExecuteNonQuery` and return the value.

See [`ExecuteCommand`](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L1933).